# Is it possible to disable confirmation dialogs in Android 4.4?

Tags: settings, 4.4-kitkat, system, quick-settings

I have an LG G2 which came with Jelly Bean, and I have recently updated it to Kit Kat.  I have noticed that the amount of confirmation dialogs when changing phone settings seems to have gone up from Jelly Bean (although Jelly Bean had a lot as well, IMHO).  I am of the opinion that if I change a phone setting, I want to do it, and I am sure of it.  I don't want to confirm every thing I do with the settings every single time (maybe the first time I do it on the phone, but not forever).

For example:

- On Jelly Bean, if I enable GPS via the quick settings, it would just enable.  With Kit Kat, every time I enable it via quick settings, I have to confirm twice that this is what I want to do (once for "Location consent" and again for Google's location service).  Since I like to leave GPS off until I need it to save battery (such as for my traffic app), this gets annoying really fast
- Another example that bugged me with Jelly Bean is the same on Kit Kat: every time I want to reset the phone, I have to confirm it
- Turning off mobile data warns me that I will not be able to use apps that require a data connection.  I know this.  I don't need to confirm this every time I want to disable data
- Airplane mode produces a dialog stating that I will be unable to make or receive calls with it on.  Again, I know this.  I don't need to be reminded every time
- Oddly enough, enabling/disabling Bluetooth does not produce such nags.

I was wondering if there is any way (mod, app, hack) to turn off these confirmation dialogs.  Thanks in advance for any insight.

Comment: I only recently updated and have the same issues (also, the sync switch in the quick settings need to be confirmed every time...). Did you find any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Try LG G2 tweak progs / xposed modules, like LTweaks, GravityBox, G2 Xposed, G2 TweaksBox. Or install Lollipop on it.

Comment: Hello. Can you tell how to use any of them to achieve the objective in question? It would be very helpful.